# what is the role of handle request in symfony form

Tags: symfony

I'm using FormBuilderInterface , to create my form, so i find that i can validate my form using the function  isvalid() , i have an issue with handleRequest($request) ,i did't understand what is the role of it.
here is my code :

```
function ajout2Action()
{
    $client= new \Esprit\PiBundle\Entity\Client();
    $formv= new \Esprit\PiBundle\Form\ClientType();
    $form=  $this->createForm($formv,$client);
     $request = $this->get('request');
  if($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid())
    {
         $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $em->persist($client);
         $em->flush();


}
```

thank you for your help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

straight from the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/form/introduction.html#request-handling) its used to process the form data

it takes the POST’ed data from the previous request, processes it, and runs any validation (checks integrity of expected versus received data). it only does this for POST requests

[read more](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep2/form-submit)